# ListBox Style Selected item on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selecteditem

i would like know how can i add a style when a item of the listbox is selected.
I have the following listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxDays" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WeekDayTemplate}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding WeekDayList}"  />
```

And i also have a DataTemplate to the listbox.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> 
        <DataTemplate x:Key="WeekDayTemplate"> 
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Margin="12,0,0,10" Height="100"  > 
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical"> 
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeekDayName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBorderBrush}" UseLayoutRounding="True" /> 
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortDate}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneBorderBrush}" Margin="25,0,12,0" />                     
                </StackPanel> 
            </StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>                 
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

At the moment when i select an item of the listbox no color change happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to change the style of the template `ListBoxItem` which the `ListBox` generates for each of the items that it renders. Your updated template needs to customise the Selected visual state. You can then associate this new template with your `ListBox` via the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` property.

There is a good tutorial, with sourcecode to download, here:

http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part1-Control-Template