# How to change color of the selected ListView item [WP8.1]

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a C# project for Windows Phone 8.1, and I can't believe that I've already wasted almost a day looking for a solution to such a trivial problem:

I have a page defined with XAML, on that page I have a ListView. At some point, I want one of the list view items to become selected, so I call myListView.SelectedIndex = whatever. Now I want that item to be distinguished visually from other items, for example, have its text drawn with a different color. How do I do that? Here are the relevant parts of code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myListItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding displayName}" 
            Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
            />
   </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView 
    x:Name="myListView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myListItemTemplate}" 
    >
</ListView>
```

Is it possible with XAML alone? Or can in be done in the C# code, just when I set myListView.SelectedIndex value?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Andrei, you can adapt the code I have for a LongListSelector over to a ListView pretty easy.  I think I explain it pretty well.  Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070203/wp8-highlight-selecteditem-longlistselector/25101536#25101536

Comment: I tried such an approach, it works but it's too slow when the list of items is large. I was hoping it's possible to specify the selected item style in the XAML itself, rather than set the color in data, looping through the whole collection.

Comment: Yeah the solution is void of any optimization so people can understand it better.  If you want to avoid the looping, you need to Databind the SelectedIndex to your ViewModel, and when that changes raise the events.  If you want a total XAML solution, I can probably write you a sample when I get home.

Comment: Check solution again for a Pure XAML solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

K, Andrei I think the solutions provided are quite good, it just buggy.  Here is mine.

XAML : Pay attention to the SelectedUnfocused

---

```
    <ListView x:Name="mylistview">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">                    
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">                                
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">                                                
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Border x:Name="myback" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>                                
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" FontSize="22"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Song}" FontSize="22"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

---

C# (A sample model)

```
public class sample_data
{
    public sample_data(string artist, string song)
    {
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.Song = song;
    }

    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Song { get; set; }
}

private ObservableCollection<sample_data> CreateData()
{
    //List<sample_data> my_list = new List<sample_data>();
    ObservableCollection<sample_data> my_list = new ObservableCollection<sample_data>();

    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Body of Christ"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Christ Again"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "A Night With the Lord"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Touch Me Jesus"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "I Found Jesus (With Someone Else)"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Savior Self"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Christ What a Day"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Three Times My Savior"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Jesus Touched Me"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Lord is my Savior"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "I Wasn't Born Again Yesterday"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Pleasing Jesus"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Faith + 1", "Jesus (Looks Kinda Hot)"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_data("Butters", "What What"));
    return my_list;
}

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<sample_data> sd = this.CreateData();
    mylistview.ItemsSource = sd;
}
```

---

Screenshot of it running:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bump this, but what if I want to use binding to a property in my class and also use this to define custom styles? I want to use `{Binding Property}` inside of the `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Hi, I'm programming ListView for Universal Windows Platform and this is not working for me. Does something change for Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a style for your ListBoxItem and use storyboards.

Here is a sample :

```
  <Page.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <!-- Define style -->
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <!-- Define style -->
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Grid Margin="0,5" x:Name="container" Background="Transparent">
            <!-- Definition of your list item. -->
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the definition of the list view :

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}" SelectionMode="Single" />
```

Comment: I added the piece of code you provided to my XAML, however it did not change the appearance of the selected item. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: SelectionMode is already single, the default. After I've added ItemContainerStyle to ListView, something changed, and your code seems to start taking effect, but it broke the data binding: the list is no longer being populated from the model data source.

Comment: It's official now: a whole day wasted just trying to change the color of the selected item...

Comment: did you copy and paste without re-adding itemsource back in?

Comment: ItemSource is still there. Can anyone point me to a working sample code for Windows Phone 8.1? The WP7 code does not work with WP8.1.

Comment: You should try to bind the selected event item and see if the event os launched. You should try to replace the listview by a listbox, and tell us what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you need to set a style with a trigger on the selected property. Its toughto yype in code on my phone but a quick google will show you a ton of examples or here:[ListBox Style Selected item on windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196364/listbox-style-selected-item-on-windows-phone)

Comment: This example uses data binding to change the selected item state, which is fine a for a few items, but highly inefficient for large lists: every time I need to change selection, I would need to enumerate the whole list. I was hoping for a solution that would not require that.

Comment: I don't know what you read, but the answer to the question I linked used a template that was applied to a listitem. I also stated to use a property trigger to apply the style. neither uses a looping strategy.

Comment: I think you replied to the wrong comment, lol. chubosaurus comment uses a looping strategy

Comment: If you look at the example you linked, you will see that it uses the data binding to the property IsSelected, that's what I was referring to, and it's not a good solution for large data sets. As for triggers, I could not find a sample code that would work with Windows Phone 8.1 The article you linked to is for WP7, which does not work with WP8.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your class a boolean variable IsSelected, and convert it to a bg color. For example:

```
   <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToBackgroundColorConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding displayName}" 
                       Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
        </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
```

|

```
class IsSelectedToBackgroundColorConverter: IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        bool IsSelected = (bool)value;

        if (IsSelected)
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush red = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);

            return red;
        }
        else
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush transparent = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);

            return transparent;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's slow when the data set is large. Besides, it does not fit the MVVM philosophy too well: the 'selected' property belong to the view, not to the data. The solution provided by Chubosaurus Software is much better in this regard. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the following to App.xaml

`</Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush"     Color="#92D050" />
    <Application.Resources>`

The "hex-Color" will be the selected item color in a ListView at application scope

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it may help you.

```
if (e.AddedItems != null) {
    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems) {
        ListViewItem litem = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
        if (litem != null) {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(litem, "Unfocused", true);
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(litem, "Normal", true);
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(litem, "Selected", true);
        }
    }
}
if (e.RemovedItems != null) {
    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems) {
        ListViewItem litem = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
        if (litem != null) {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(litem, "Unselected", true);
        }
    }
}
```