# Using PhoneAccentBrush in WP8.1 Universal app

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a listview in a page specific to the WP8.1 portion of the solution, with a standard `ObservableCollection` as the itemssource. I would like to highlight the selected item, which for the moment is using a datatemplate of just a textblock. It seems this feature is supported in the base WP8.1 control, only in the W8.1 version.

Following the solution presented here; [How to change color of the selected ListView item [WP8.1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596398/how-to-change-color-of-the-selected-listview-item-wp8-1)
I managed to get it to highlight with a specified colour, but I'd really like to be able to bind to the phone's accent colour, which I'm certain that I was able to bind to this in WP8.0, but the resource isn't available in the page in the universal app.

for the moment I have replaced the direct colour specification of 'red' with

```
<ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{ThemeResource PhoneChromeColor}"/>
```

which works to highlight the item, but obviously not the colour I want.

Can I get access to the `PhoneAccentBrush` in the xaml? Is there a better way to achieve my goal? I am not a professional developer, so some 'user friendly' guidance would be most helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `To` property of `ColorAnimation` expects an object of type Color. `PhoneAccentBrush` is of the SolidColorBrush type.

Here are two suggestions (I haven't tested them, but I think they should work):

1. Objects of the `SolidColorBrush` type have a property `Color` of type `Color` which you can use like this `{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource PhoneColorBrush}}`.
2. You can also use the `PhoneAccentColor` static resource, which is basically the color of the `PhoneAccentBrush` brush, like this: `{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}`.

Also, if you're not really animating the color, you can just change the whole brush with something like this:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I hope some of these would work for you! :)

Comment: Marked as answer, as replacing `<ColorAnimation...` in my code with the `<ObjectAnimation...` worked a treat. The selected item is now highlighting with the same colour as the user selected theme on the emulator. Will also keep the other methods mentioned in mind for future use too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by agreeing that @Scoregraphic is correct. Your error message is something that is unique to you. That being said, you should know that the accent brush on Windows is always purple. Using the accent brush has little value because of this.

You can overcome this with device-specific styling. This means you can use accent brush in your Phone app but in your Windows app you add whatever logic you want to have a color that makes sense.

I discuss device-specific styling more here:

> http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Developing-Universal-Windows-Apps-with-C-and-XAML/03#time=27m00s

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Jerry, Yasen's answer above got me the result I wanted, but marking yours as helpful too as I had not stumbled across this resource and will definitely work my way through them.

Answer (score 0):

The `PhoneAccentBrush` is available through `{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}` in the XAML

Comment: that particular resource is not available to intellisense in the 'To' property. I tried it any way and received the following error exception message.   `Message "Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation.To' because the type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush' cannot be assigned to the type 'Windows.UI.Color'. [Line: 186 Position: 201]" string
`

Comment: Do you really need to set the color or would it also be possible to just set the brush?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean, as I don't see the point in the xaml solution provided by Chubosaurus (in the page I linked to) where there is the possibility of using the brush? Can you please elaborate?