# Change ListView Selected item background color

Tags: xaml, listview, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I want to change the background colour to Transparent of a Selected item of ListView. My code :

```
<Grid>
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
                                <ListViewItem>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="AlignCenter"
                                            Foreground="White" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="MAPS"
                                            Foreground="White" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ListViewItem>
                            </ListView>
</Grid>
```

SO, what i want is change the background colour to transparent when an Item is being selected from the ListView. Is it possible in XAML with UWP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Highlight color of the selected ListView item in UWP (Windows 10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302146/how-to-change-highlight-color-of-the-selected-listview-item-in-uwp-windows-10)

Comment: Yes. that is exactly what I was looking for. Solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. That's also the first google result when you google your question + "uwp" ;)