# How to change the listview activated color in xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I want to change the highlighted color on clicking ListView item in Xamarin Forms - UWP. In android i am setting style to fix this.`<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>` How can i achieve the same is UWP. Images added: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgeru.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Navigate into your UWP project, Open your App.xaml, and place the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">

<!--Your accent color-->
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FF055ADA</Color>                

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.9" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentLowBrush" Color="ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.6" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentMediumBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.8" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.9" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.6" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.8" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This should work by overriding the default UWP ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here : 
[How to change Highlight color of the selected ListView item in UWP (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302146/how-to-change-highlight-color-of-the-selected-listview-item-in-uwp-windows-10)

Change current resources

```
Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

or define your own `ListViewItemPresenter`

Comment: Where u use this lines of code ?? in the App.cs of native UWP project ?

Comment: Am used it in native UWP MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Try to use it in App.xaml.cs

Comment: It shows error when used in constructor of App. If it is used in Onlauched method no error occurs. But still highlighted color is not changed. Error that is got is `System.Exception occurred
  HResult=0x8000FFFF
  Message=Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>` when used in contructor