# C# UWP ListView remove all visual effects

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, styles, mousehover

In UWP I have a listview.

XAML:

```
 <Grid Background="Gray">
    <ListView Name="lvMain" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="120" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsList, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:Int32">
                <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Padding="10">
                    <Grid Background="Green"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And in Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> ItemsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ItemsList.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And the results are as bellow:

[image]

How to remove all the effects/lights on mouse hover from listview?

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting color you see when you hovering mouse over an item is defined in [the default style and template for ListViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx).

Specifically, search for this line in the default style

```
PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
```

You can create a special style for `ListViewItem` and set this color to `Transparent`, and apply the special style to your `ListView`.

This page provides the guide to [work with styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles).

Edit: I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32302146/815938) asking similar question, the accepted answer shows how to edit the template in Visual studio.

Comment: What about those lines between items?

Comment: Try to hover with mouse, over unselected items. These lines will be lighten near your cursor.

Answer (score 1):

> What about those lines between items?

Add to @kennyzx's reply. The lines you're talking about actually is [Reveal Highlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal). You could see the default style of ListViewItem in  the `\(Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\your sdk version\Generic\generic.xaml`.

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemRevealStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                    x:Name="Root"
                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                    FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                    CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                    CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                    DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}"
                    DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                    FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                    FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                    PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                    PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                    PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                    SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"
                    SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}"
                    SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                    PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                    SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                    DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                    DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                    ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}"
                    RevealBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}"
                    RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}"
                    RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrush}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ListViewItemPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You could see it uses many 'Reveal' Theme Resources. All these resources name contain the word 'Reveal'. For example, `RevealBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}"`.

If you do not want it, you could replace them all.